# Making Table <tr> to display one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnuhxbsu/)

Here is my html code

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none">Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none">Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output i am getting is like

```
System Architect
Accountant
```

But i want to display like

```
System Architect | Accountant
```

i.e., Row should be look like column.

**Note :**

I am hiding the first td, because my search plugin(datatables) will consider the first `<td>` inside the `<tr>`

How can i do this ?

Comment: Your jsFiddle is empty. Now regarding your issue, why don't you set it in same TR?

Comment: If you want to display information side by side you should place the data in sibling `td` elements, or don't use a table at all.

Comment: @A.Wolff Same TR ? You mean only one tr ?

Comment: @quickbloxapi Ya but i really don't get what you are expecting. Explain instead why would you need that. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using this plugin https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html It requires the search item to be inside the tr's td ..

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with those hidden `td`s. Can't you have the names as data attributes in the second `td` and completely remove the first `td`s?

Comment: In this case I would recommend you use `divs` (tableless) instead of `table`. Tables should be used when you need to display a content in the form of a table, otherwise just use CSS (to align it anyway you want).

Comment: Why dont you change your structure. Why using tables when you are not using for what it is meant for?

Comment: @A.Wolff This is the reason https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html , this api requires that structure

Comment: If you want rows to look like columns, I think you can try `tr { display:table-cell}`

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior Even i don't want to use the table. But the api requires. The api will display the datas in row but it need to display like coloumn wise. If it change the siblings and parent, the property given by api wont' work..

Comment: its not a right way to use table... instead of table try to use div structure

Comment: @quickbloxapi You still didn't explain **why** then you need to use datatable plugin???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a simple css could fix this:

```
#example tr {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is really great. ! Will accept in few min. Cheers

Comment: @quickbloxapi This gives that with datatable: http://jsfiddle.net/smrtj1ph/2/  Is it really expected behaviour??? Anyway, this doesn't make sense

Comment: @A.Wolff Here's the exact the the answer tries to say, and what i expect.. http://jsfiddle.net/vnuhxbsu/6/ just row's look, look like coloumn

Comment: @quickbloxapi BUT doesn't work with datatable plugin, breaking design...

Comment: @A.Wolff The design looks ok and it works good. I can accept that it is bad practise, but i don't find breaking design...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to force a non table structure on a table element. Even though this is possible using CSS (as others have stated), this is bad practice and should be avoided. I would recommend switching to a different UI plugin that uses `divs` or list elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
#example tr {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

please use this...

Answer (score 0):

use `tr { display:table-cell};` in CSS, add additional `<tr><td>` for `|`

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudhansu23/7hyp11u2/1/)

Comment: See what it gives with datatable: http://jsfiddle.net/smrtj1ph/

Comment: @A.Wolff Oh my worthy!! that's bad! but is OP using datatable? I understand this solution with datatable is a **NO**

Comment: Indeed OP's question is not clear!

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary  Here's the one that i got from the below answerer http://jsfiddle.net/vnuhxbsu/6/

Comment: @quickbloxapi I've updated my fiddle, have a look at that, you can adjust the width of the cells.